# Can I wear pendant that's symbol of peace?

Tags: personal-practice, iconography

A year ago I bought one and I just got it is NDC (Nuclear Disarmament Campaign). I don't mind but I wanted feeling peace through everything what I need to having it. And soon I'm gonna practicing vipassana meditation. 
Can I wear pendant that I have ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Comment: Is this a question about protocol at a retreat or a question about orthodoxy with respect to amulets? (Amulets are a big part of lay Buddhism in Thailand for example) If it is about protocol, check with the retreat center, they vary widely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Mr/Mrs user73898 is doing meditaion seriously in one stream, its would be out of any benefit, if it is done without taking the 8 precepts. Beautification is one Sila of it. Its not proper and every fellow yogi, next to the reality would just think "Oh dear, how mindful... how serious".

If you find a mediation group that has no propel with that, or does not urge Mr/Mrs., run away, all they are doing is for their livelihood and without compassion for Mr/Mrs, without any benefit. Withdraw from sensual pleasure and outwardly notions of conceit (Sila), are prerequisite of meditaion (Samadhi). Not done the raw stuff, how would you waste time in grinding the tree in the forest for getting a nice chair.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Comment: Thank you so much @-}-- Your guideline is treasure. I'll keep it all in my mind. I wouldn't do without knowing and without Buddha's path. Monks helping me too. Seriously I'll do as you guided. I wanted learn Buddhism ultimately. Even I need start , my knowledge isn't enough to get peace in my mind. Thank you so much @-}--

Comment: Mr/mrs User73989 may, if he/she likes, take the five or eight precepts for him/her self, which is very useful to train, even in "normal" life. If doing a retreat, it should be done anyhow, and as told, don't access communities who do not do such. It's how ever of great use, if approaching a monk or a non, or somebody who knows well about silas and also practices them, and request the precepts. It goes deep and so it has its deep impact and benefit, as righteous prerequisite and security of having best and even real fruits.

Comment: Not much knowledge required to come to peace: [The rewards of virtue](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sila/index_en.html), and the [The Eight Precepts](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sila/atthasila_en.html) Mr/Mrs @user73898

Comment: As I'll start to learn and will find monk I'll learn about sila and eight precepts and as you said it'll deep and will deep impact and benefit I'll have treasure through. Thank you so much @-}--

Answer (score 3):

That is in harmony with nonviolent Buddhism however on a vipassana retreat there is noble silence, and anything worn that said anything would be as distracting as spoken words.

Comment: What is nonviolent Buddhism, Mr Uilium and could it be that he does misunderstand the Hippy-movement with dhamma? And does ones beard speaks?

Answer (score 0):

What you ware does not effect your path or your practice. In Lord Buddha's time people reached Nirvana while wearing nothing,While working and etc.

Focus on your path do not take concerns about these minor things.

Answer (score 0):

For sitting meditation, you can't go wrong by simplifying.  Just wear simple, loose clothing, and leave the rest in your bag (good) or at home (better). 
You can always wear whatever you like outside.  Inside, be non-distracting:  it's just a question of politeness to your fellow meditators.

Answer (score 0):

For practising any other branch except that of Mahayana / Vajrayana, no restrictions for mundane practitioners' outfit exist, to the best of my knowledge.

However, if you are practicing in any Vajrayana lineage, you should ask your lama, because bearing a visible jewelery / amulet could be a potential obstacle to keeping layman'v vows on Mahayana Sojong days.

Comment: Thanks all of you people reaching for help me. Thank you so much @-}-- L<3ve Buddha @-}--